# Automatic #defines according to Debug/Release config in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I have debug output in my program like this:

```
#define DEBUG
...
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "[RE_words] " << m_re << std::endl;
#endif
```

and `DEBUG` is defined in my program manually. I always comment out the line when I make a release version. In Visual Studio, there are also Configurations for *Debug* vs *Release* versions which handle the commandline etc. used for compiling. Can I also use the Configuration "Debug" to automatically define `DEBUG` to the compiler? How?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The Visual Studio automatically defines _DEBUG symbol for Debug builds (and NDEBUG for non-debug builds).

Another way to do this is to go to the project settings -> configuration properties -> C/C++ -> preprocessor, and edit the preprocessor definitions manually.

See also:
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2290616/562593) explains the differences between _DEBUG and NDEBUG in more detail.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5474282/562593) explains the purpose of the NDEBUG symbol and whether or not is it defined by the standard.

Comment: Incidentally, NDEBUG is the portable solution. It is kind of unfortunate that no standard symbol exists for DEBUG builds.

Comment: Hi, how can you be sure that vs defines those macros? on msdn it just mention _DEBUG, not NDEBUG, where can I see a list with all the macros VS does for you please?

Comment: @Icebone1000: I have added a link to an answer explaining whether or not is NDEBUG a standard symbol and why would it be considered portable. See the [list of predefined macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.110).aspx) in the VS.

Comment: Note that if you edit the definitions manually, you might need to restart VS before they are recognised.

Answer (score 11):

Use `_DEBUG`.  Visual C++ defines this for a Debug configuration.  Check out the preprocessor directives for the Debug Configuration in your project's properties dialog.

Answer (score 5):

I too thought I just had to look at the preprocessor property and remove _DEBUG.  Visual Studio tries to help out by setting _DEBUG if you select one of the debug run-time library options.

On the project property page *Configuration Properties\C/C++\Code Generation* the option selected for *Runtime Library* affects several defines.  When selecting a debug library (**/MTd** or **/MDd**) the **_DEBUG** define ***is*** set.

See [MSDN /MD, /MT ...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx)
for more info on the switches.  There are several #defines that are set based on these options.  They are pretty invisible when trying to find who sets a #define before you even include any header files!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should check project options page, Compile->Advanced compile options.
However, VS by default automatically defines DEBUG directive for Debug mode.

Comment: I believe it's the `_DEBUG` directive. Note the underscore.