# What is the NDEBUG preprocessor macro used for (on different platforms)?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, c-preprocessor, ndebug

I'm interested in what purpose various platforms / compilers ("implementations") / frameworks assign to the the **C** and C++ preprocessor macro `NDEBUG`.

The **C** as well as the C++ standard only mention this definition once, namely to control the behavior of the `assert()` macro.

I would ask to include only specific answers, where you *know* that a certain platform / framework / library for **C** or C++ uses the `NDEBUG` definition to enable or disable anything else **in addition to the standard defined `assert()` macro**.

One reason for asking this question has been that MS (Visual-C++) always(?) uses "their" [`_DEBUG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b98s6w8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) define to distinguish between debug and release stuff and I was wondering if this is a common practice for a library / platform to have their "own" debug define or whether other libraries / platforms use `NDEBUG`for their debug related stuff.

Comment: The link to the MSDN page is now dead. Archive URL: https://web.archive.org/web/20110412105153/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b98s6w8(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That is a decision up to the maintainer(s) of the framework in question. Since such decisions are subject to change, it's nothing you should *rely* on. I use NDEBUG as a toggle for everything debug-related (e.g. trace outputs), but I might change my mind in the next release. No answer anyone could give here is a replacement for checking the API documentation of the frameworks you use in a given project.

That being said, using NDEBUG in library / framework headers, for anything else *but* `assert()`, would be a rather dumb design decision. The application programmer is *explicitly* allowed to set / unset NDEBUG however he sees fit, before and / or after including the headers of any library or framework, so the lib / framework maintainer could not rely on NDEBUG being set for a release lib or not set for a debugging lib. I doubt any significant project would have relied on NDEBUG that way.

Answer (score 34):

The only 'standard' thing about `NDEBUG` is that it's used to control whether the `assert` macro will expand into something that performs a check or not.  MSVC helpfully defines this macro in release build configurations by defining it in the project for you.  You can change that manually by editing the project configuration.  Other toolchains might (or might not) do something similar.

Note that you can also change the state of the `NDEBUG` macro within a translation unit (source file) using `#define` and/or `#undef` on `NDEBUG` and re-include `assert.h` to change how the `assert` macro behaves (turn it on and off).  That behavior is mandated by the standard, and is the only time (I think) where the standard permits including a standard header a second time to change the behavior of compilation after the second inclusion.

Comment: Thanks. This is a useful clarification. It doesn't answer however whether/if it is used by some platforms/libraries for something else. (I *think* its not used for anything else (than `assert()`) in MSVC, but I'm not even sure of this.)