# gfortran warn on floating point exception

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, fortran, gfortran

I'm using gfortran for some code.  For a while now, I've been compiling with

```
-ffpe-trap=zero,overflow,invalid
```

in an attempt to hunt down some bugs. This causes my program to cease execution immediately.  There are some cases where the FPE might be OK and so a flag like:

```
-ffpe-warn=zero,overflow,invalid
```

would be very useful. Does gfortran (or any other compiler) provide anything like this?  If not, are there any workarounds? My current thought is to create a C function to register a signal handler to write out the warning, although I have no idea how to go about doing that.

Comment: How would this putative runtime warning mechanism work?

Comment: Does gfortran provide the (relatively new) ieee_arithmetic intrinsic module ?  If it does, that would give you the tools you need to do your own f-p 'error' trapping in Fortran.

Comment: @DavidHefferman When the runtime exception is raised, the execution stops, a message is printed about where the exception occured and the program exits.  I would just like to be notified when/where the exception occured (a message to stderr maybe?) and allow execution to proceed.  Maybe that's not possible ... I don't know too much about how these things work ...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't know.  The code is not actually my code, and needs to be portable to a large number of different compilers -- I just ask about gfortran since that is the compiler that I typically use in my development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a way of warning on encountering a floating point exception. But both gfortran and ifort have signal handling routines. See for example the gfortran documentation of [signal](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gfortran/SIGNAL.html) and
the Intel Fortran Compiler [User and Reference Guides (warning: large PDF)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gchttp://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/fortran/lin/main_for_lin.pdf) (see page 410 on wards).

> You can establish one of the following actions for a signal with a call to `signal`:
>
> - Ignore the specified signal (identified by number).
> - Use the default action for the specified signal, which can reset a previously established action.
> - Transfer control from the specified signal to a procedure to receive the signal, specified by name.

In your case, you would want to write a function to do something when a floating point exception occurs (e.g. print file name/line number), and use the third option in the above list.

Unfortunately this is not very portable: take a look at [this page](https://support.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/index.php/Using_Signals#Trapping_signals_in_Fortran) for examples of signal handling for various compilers. You could wrap some code in preprocessor macros if you want to

- compile with multiple compilers
- only use the signal handling routines if some preprocessor flag is set (cf. [`-NDEBUG`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473556/what-is-the-ndebug-preprocessor-macro-used-for-on-different-platforms))

**Update:** Ultimately the exception handling facilities of the `ieee_exceptions` intrinsic module would be the portable way to do this, as suggested by High Performance Mark.

Comment: Good to know about Fortran's signal handling -- Though I would probably do that part in C since it is a little more standardized.  I still have no idea how to get the line number/filename/stacktrace where the exception occured -- googling around a bit makes me think it would be quite messy business.