# CMake, g++ : set CXX Flags -02 but -03 is still there?

Tags: compiler-construction, g++, cmake, flags

i think want to add specific compiler cxx flags to the release-mode. I read here in another thread that -O2 are good flags for release configuration

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall -O2")
```

but if i check now the CXX Flags

```
message(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})
```

he write me

```
-O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall -O2
```

1. Did it make sense using -02 instead of -03 ?
2. How can i delete -03 from the Flags?
3. What is DNDEBUG using for?

best regards

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use compiler documentation to see difference between O2 and O3
 and make your choice (: for example - [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options). [Here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GCC_optimization) you can found recommendation to use O2 for **stability**.

---

You can use this macro for removing flags:

```
macro(remove_cxx_flag flag)
  string(REPLACE "${flag}" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
endmacro()
```

**[usage]**

```
  macro(remove_cxx_flag flag)
    string(REPLACE "${flag}" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
  endmacro()

  message(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}) # print "-O3 -DNDEBUG"
  remove_cxx_flag("-O3")
  message(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}) # print "-DNDEBUG"
```

Here is used macro because you need to update variable from parent scope, read this - http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:macro (or you can use function with PARENT_SCOPE modifier)

---

NDEBUG used for disabling [assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), see [What is the NDEBUG preprocessor macro used for (on different platforms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473556/what-is-the-ndebug-preprocessor-macro-used-for-on-different-platforms) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Iam not sure how to use macros in cmake at all. Can you explain me how to use your posted macro for replacing the flags? Thanks ! :)

Comment: I have found this: remove(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})     is this way ok too?

Comment: Oh ~ thats bad. Because it works so fine xD . . .    What should i do when i want to remove the -O3 flag from CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE for example ? I do not really know how to use this macro you post me. ?

Answer (score 4):

`${val}` references a variable.

Your `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall -O2")`

Adds previously configured CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE variables.

So change it to

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-DNDEBUG -Wall -O2")`

`-DNDEBUG` removes assert from your code - skips it.
More at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Answer (score 2):

### Modifying the flags

If you want to override the default `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE` or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` variable for the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` `release` which is set to `-O3 -DNDEBUG` you'll need to do so before the `project` line. In essence, if the release build type defaults don't suit you, you'll need to take matters into your own hands. An additional possibility is to handle this in the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.8 )

set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "" CACHE STRING "" )       
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "" CACHE STRING "" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "" CACHE STRING "" )
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "" CACHE STRING "" )

project(hello)

set( SOURCE_FILES
    hello.c foo.c )

add_executable( hello
    ${SOURCE_FILES} )


set_source_files_properties( foo.c 
    PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-O3 -DNDEBUG" )

set_source_files_properties( hello.c 
    PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS -O0 )
```