# ASSERT that works on Release mode too?

Tags: c++, std, assert

Where can I find an `ASSERT` similar to the `assert(...)` macro from the standard C++ library (the one defined in `<cassert>`), but that works on Release mode too? Or how should I write one?

I like `assert(...)` because it automatically prints the line my source file where the assertion failed, as well as the assertion expression. I expect those features (if possible) in the Release mode `ASSERT` as well.

Comment: Just do not define `NDEBUG` and standard assert would work

Comment: @Lol4t0 But that won't mess with other compiler optimizations in Release mode?

Comment: At least it is intended and _documented_ behavior (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)

Answer (score 5):

Basically `assert` is a macro that evaluates the expression and if it fails prints something and then `abort`s. It's not that hard to write something similar, something like.

```
#define ASSERT(x) do { if( !(x) ) { printfunc( #x ); abort(); } } while(0)
```

Then you can modify that in order to suit your requirements. For example you might want not to `abort` in release mode. You could also adjust your printouts (to include just the information that you think is useful), in order to get file and line information you would use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros (btw the `#x` in the define expands to a string literal containing the expression `x`).

Answer (score 2):

In your release build, don't define `NDEBUG`, and `assert` will work.

Comment: If I #undef NDEBUG, that won't mess with other compiler optimizations in Release mode?

Comment: See [what-is-the-ndebug-preprocessor-macro-used-for-on-different-platforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473556/what-is-the-ndebug-preprocessor-macro-used-for-on-different-platforms). In short `NDEBUG` is only used to disable `assert`.

Answer (score 0):

You can undefine NDEBUG

```
#undef NDEBUG
```

near the assert statement

or you can define your own assert

```
#define assert(x) printf(...)
```

Comment: You probably have to undefine NDEBUG before including cassert.

Comment: If I `#undef NDEBUG`, that won't mess with other compiler optimizations in Release mode?

Answer (score 0):

I've rolled out my own assertions that always fire in release mode too, based on this [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/assertions/184403861):

This is the GIST of it, with me not providing the actual implementation (of AbstractAsserter, which is based on the article), but you get the idea:

```
#include <iostream>

struct AbstractAsserter
{
    virtual void doAssert(const char* expr, const char* file, int line, const char* function) const
    {
        std::cout << "Asserting now at " << expr << ", " << file << ", " << line << ", " << function << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Local
{
  const char* function_;
  const char* expr_;
  const char* file_;
  int line_;
  Local( const char* f, const char* ex, const char* file, int line )
  : function_( f ), expr_( ex ), file_( file ), line_( line )
  { }
  Local operator << ( const AbstractAsserter& impl )
  {
    impl.doAssert( expr_, file_, line_, function_ );
    return *this;
  }
};

// More to be added as required...
#if defined( __GNUC__ )
# define WE_FUNCTION __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#elif defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901)
# define WE_FUNCTION __func__
#else
# define WE_FUNCTION "null_func()"
#endif


#define WE_ASSERT( expr )\
  if( expr );\
  else Local( WE_FUNCTION, #expr, __FILE__, __LINE__ )\
    << AbstractAsserter();


int main() {
    WE_ASSERT(!"bad BAD BOY!");
    return 0;
}
```

With this structure, your implementation may also do some critical saving of state etc (if you deem your program state trustworthy...debatable).

Answer (score 0):

Using the std `assert` in release mode (where, by the comments, you would like compiler optimizations enabled), isn't a problem per se, as is established by the other answers. Writing a custom one has been done, so there's not much problem there.

However, to quote the [Dr. Dobb's article](http://www.drdobbs.com/assertions/184403861):

> Do use assertions *liberally* throughout your code; they are watchful, reliable guards that protect you (your program) from insanity

If you are worried to have assertion + compiler optimizations, then these two thing are a bit add odds conceptually:

- Asserts should and can be used liberally, with the intention of finding bugs early, and *mostly* so that it doesn't matter whether the assert code hurts performance.
- If you want/need to run with optimizations, you may not like the performance hit the additional (now optimized, but still) assert code gives you.

So, in summary, I see the use of a relase mode assert, but make sure to keep it separate from the "normal" assert, where most people would assume it to be off in release mode.