# Can I capture the underlying value of one macro when defining another?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Imagine I want to `#define` a macro such that it is equal to the *current* value of another macro (if such a concept exists).

For example:

```
#include "def_a.h"  // defines macro A
#define B A
```

This defines `B` to be `A`. If `A` later changes definition (i.e., through a redefinition) the value of `B` also changes (because `B` expands to `A` at the point of use, which further expands to the new value of `A`).

What I'd like is some way to "bake in" the value of `A` into `B` so that `B` just expands to the value of `A`, not `A` itself.

For example:

```
#define A first
#define B BAKE_IN(A)
#undef A
#define A second
#define C BAKE_IN(A)
#undef A
#define A third

// here I want B to expand to first, and C to expand to second
```

Of course `BAKE_IN` is not a real thing, but I'm wondering if there is some way to achieve this effect.

Now, I didn't really say what should happen if A itself is defined in terms of other macros, but I'm OK both with "one level of expansion" (i.e., B gets the value of A is expanded, so further macros remain) and also "full expansion" (i.e., A is fully expanded, recursively, as it would be at a point of use).

Comment: Why you care too much about the steps of substitution and not about the final result. `#define B A` is sufficient to get the value of A but with two steps. Seeing the number of upvote did not get what did I miss here. I feel like you want to take the long road to rome.

Comment: Ok, I was not sure ... does someone know how to mark a question as duplicate without closing it?

Comment: As far as I know, those are mutually exclusive. If a question is marked as duplicate, it gets closed with the little banner at the top directing you to the old question.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you are trying to achieve ? assuming that I cannot C#.

Comment: @Sabrina - I want to `#include` a header file with specific macros defined/not-defined and then "capture" the value of a macro that this header file defines. Later, the macro that I captured from may change value, but I want the original value.

Comment: @Sabrina: That is no way related to C#

Comment: @beeonarope: it is rarely good style to redefine a CPP macro, although it can be useful occasionally, for example with X-macros. What sort of value might your macro have?

Comment: @rici - indeed, I do it pretty much never (this would be the my first use in recent memory). In fact, even though I do use X macros, I do with the "user form" that takes a function-as-macro as doesn't need redefinition (attributed to Andrei Alexandrescu at the [bottom of this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-x-macro/228700289#highlighter_616127), for example). This is one case where I thought it might be useful. Basically I'm [trying](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42093734/149138) to capture the value of the `assert` macro so I can re-use the implementation, after `#undef NDEBUG`.

Comment: ... ultimately though I don't think this approach could work even if `BAKE_IN` existed because I won't be able to include `assert.h` again with `NDEBUG` restored. Still I guess the question stands alone as somewhat useful to understand what is and isn't possible in the pre-processor.

Comment: @beeonrope: basically, this isn't possible with the preprocessor and even if it were, it wouldn't help with your use case. I put a suggestion about the assert use case as an answer to your other question; in this context, I'm going to stick with the answer I provided: you can freeze a macro only if it's value is an integer, and only with the black pp magic of boost-pp.

Comment: Good enough for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are never replaced in the body of a `#define` directive, so there is no way to define a macro as the current value of another macro, except for the limited case of macros whose value is a constant arithmetic expression.

In the latter case, you can use `BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT` from the [Boost preprocessor library.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/assign_slot.html) (Although most of the Boost libraries are C++-specific, the Boost preprocessor library works for both C and C++, and has no dependency on any other Boost component.)

Comment: Your "exception" is none actually. And this is about C, not C++.

Comment: @olaf: the boost preprocessor library works in both C and C++.

Comment: @Olaf - does the underlying technique `BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT` uses work in C then, or are the preprocessor rules different?

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Boost is a C++ library. And it cannot change how cpp works.

Comment: @olaf: boost-pp is not a c++ library. It is true that it does not change how cpp works -- but it has lots of tricks to make it do things you might not expect are possible.

Comment: @rici: Ok, until then I assumed it was part of boost, which **is** C++ only. However, it might provide help for OP, but can't do what he asks for. So we have an XY-problem.

Comment: @olaf: i don't know whether OP could use a numeric-only solution but perhaps other programmers who stumble upon this question have a problem which the `BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT` macro can solve. That's the reason I mentioned it rather than just saying "No, you can't do that".

Comment: Although in my case I wasn't using a constant expression, this is exactly the kind of knowledge I'll stash away for future use, so it is very useful to me. Thanks @rici

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a clean solution. The closest thing that I found is to preserve "stringified" values within `char` arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BAKE_IN(X, id) BAKE_IN_REAL(X ## _, X, id)
#define BAKE_IN_REAL(X, Y, id) static const char X ## id[] = #Y;
#define BAKE_OUT(X, id) X ## _ ## id

#define A first
BAKE_IN(A, 1)
#define B BAKE_OUT(A, 1)
#undef A

#define A second
BAKE_IN(A, 2)
#define C BAKE_OUT(A, 2)
#undef A

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", B); // prints "first"
    printf("%s\n", C); // prints "second"
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is that `BAKE_IN` macro declares object named as e.g. `A_1`, which holds the current expansion of `A`.

There are two major limitations:

- Every pair of `BAKE_IN` and `BAKE_OUT` needs unique id
- The expansion is only available in "stringified" form

Comment: Thanks! This is quite useful when you need a string version of the macro, which is actually the case for some type of diagnostics, so I'll probably use this in the future. I accepted the other answer in this case because it was more directly applicable (since I definitely don't need a stringified form for my use case), but this is a good contribution.