# Finding Debug or Release mode in C++ through coding

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

My application saves a few files in specified paths depending on which mode the program is running....that is either debug or release mode...How can I find out through coding that in which mode my program is currently running on? so that I can write the correct if else statement..

Please help me..

I am using VS2005 with C++98..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [preprocessor symbols `_DEBUG` and `NDEBUG`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604340/678093):

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    std::cout << "in debug mode";
#else
    std::cout << "in release mode";
#endif
```