# Macros for Debug and Release modes

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am writing application on C++ .NET in Visual Studio 2008. I want to ask if there is standard macros to know if application is in Debug or Release mode.

For example I want to write something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Debuge Mode")
#endif
```

Comment: See also [c++ - _DEBUG vs NDEBUG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290509/debug-vs-ndebug)

Comment: Spelling error in string: *debuge*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio predefines `_DEBUG` as the debug macro.

Comment: @ViTo: For release you simple check if `_DEBUG` is not defined: `#ifndef _DEBUG`.

Comment: @ViTo: That's not the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137723/write-logs-in-visual-studio-2008 here is question