# Write logs in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, c++-cli, logging

I am writing application on C++ .NET in Visual Studio 2008. I want to ask if there is standard function for writing **logs** ?

### Edited

it mean I can write such code and where I can see output logs ?

```
#ifdef DEBUG
Trace::Write("Message", "Category"); 
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Trace::Write("Message", "Category"); 
Debug::Write("Message", "Category"); // Same thing as #ifdef DEBUG Trace::Write(...)
```

is pretty much the prebuilt logging facility. To get the output to a file, append the below configuration to your `app.config` file, all the output will be written to `c:\myListener.log`:

```
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
    <listeners>
      <remove name="Default" />
      <add name="myListener"
           type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="c:\myListener.log" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Ref: [How to: Create and Initialize Trace Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t.aspx)

Comment: And where I can find log which I write ? Where can I see them ?

Comment: You'll need to make sure the user account that's running your webserver has permissions to write to the file and it's location.

Comment: Then you have no problem there with c:\myListener.log path, or actually any path you like.

Comment: Sorry but where I shall create app.config ?

Comment: Inside visual studio right click on your project and select "Add > New Item > Application Configuration File". A new item will be added to the project directory. Edit that file and you'll be good to go.

Comment: It's not work ! I have created all as you say I call System::Diagnostics::Trace::Write("Message", "Category");  this line on Form load and add config file ... But when I Run Application no myListener.log file creates ... Why ?