# Obj-C, DEBUG define log statements not working, since upgrading Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'd been happy using my debug statements until recently I upgraded Xcode and now they don't work.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define SQLLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), 
                __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define SQLLog(...)
#endif
```

What do I need to do to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot explain why it used to work and after upgrading Xcode it stopped doing so, but possibly it has to do with the fact that it does use `NDEBUG`, which stands for "non debug"; `NDEBUG` is defined in the standard, `DEBUG` is not.

Short solution to your problem should be explicitly defining the `DEBUG` symbol under your project build configuration.

Have also a look at this post about: [_DEBUG vs NDEBUG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290509/debug-vs-ndebug).

Comment: _DEBUG and NDEBUG had no effect either :( Thanks for your input