# How to use #ifdef _DEBUG on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I have a problem with _DEBUG macro on Linux C++.
I tried to use something like this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
cout << "Debug!" << endl;
#endif
```

But it doesn't work when I select Debug in IDE. However it worked on Windows.
I use Eclipse IDE for C++ coding on Linux.

Comment: You have to go into the project properties and see what Eclipse set for pre-processor flags in release and debug variants. Maybe add _DEBUG yourself.

Comment: did you use eclipse in windows?

Comment: Add the usual habit, at least with `<assert.h>` and the standard `assert` macro, is to define `NDEBUG` when you *don't want debugging*

Comment: Check [_DEBUG vs NDEBUG](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2290509/1168156)

Comment: @L7ColWinters, I didn't.

Answer (score 6):

On windows you were probably using Visual Studio, which automatically defines the **_DEBUG** symbol when building the solution in Debug mode. Symbols are usually defined when invoking the compiler, and then they will be used during the pre-processor phase.

For example, if you are using GCC via command line and you want to re-use the _DEBUG symbol because you are handling an already established codebase, you can define it using the **-D** parameter via command line.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
#ifdef _DEBUG
  std::cout << "But also Hello Stack Overflow!\n";
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with the following command line

```
 g++ -D _DEBUG define.cpp
```

will give the following result

```
Hello world!
But also Hello Stack Overflow!
```

Your best bet for eclipse cdt however could be to [modify the paths and symbols properties](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_inc.htm) in the project properties.

Answer (score 3):

If you use **cmake** put the following in your  your top-level **CMakeLists.txt** file

```
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG")
```

found on [CMake Mailinglist](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-April/036500.html)

Answer (score 0):

Put `#define _DEBUG` somewhere north of where you have this snippet, or in your project settings.

Comment: I highly recommend not having it in any c++ file.  Project settings is fine, but not in the code itself.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yeah that's true. Personally I just wouldn't use MSVC, or STL where this is heavily used, and stick to NDEBUG which is in common use.

Comment: @user1173593: You want `#define _DEBUG`... Read some of the MSVC doco for your compiler, or your STL collection.