# Having difficulty using a debugger macro

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, visual-studio-code, output

Here is the code:

```
void DBG() { cerr << "]" << endl; }
template<class H, class... T> void DBG(H h, T... t) {
    cerr << to_string(h); if (sizeof...(t)) cerr << ", ";
    DBG(t...); }

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define dbg(...) cerr << "LINE(" << __LINE__ << ") -> [" << #__VA_ARGS__ << "]: [", DBG(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define dbg(...) 0
#endif
```

Im currently using g++ on vs code on a mac and whenever I run my program using this and for example
I write `dbg(10)` on main the program does not even run and does not do anything(it outputs nothing).

How can I change this code so it would work on g++ without having to download clang?
**Note**: I saw some people use `#ifdef LOCAL` instead of `#ifdef _DEBUG` but it still doesn't work for me(does not output anything). How do I get `#ifdef LOCAL` or `#ifdef _DEBUG` to work on g++?

Comment: _DEBUG is from MSVC, try #ifdef NDEBUG

Comment: @JCWasmx86 nope still doesn't work for me

Comment: It's the other way around "NDEBUG" means not debugging, so the condition should be `#ifndef NDEBUG`.  Separately, it's best practice to reserve all-uppercase multi-letter names for preprocessor defines and never use them for other purposes, so I'd suggest calling your function "dbg" and your macro "DBG".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use #ifdef \_DEBUG on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034700/how-to-use-ifdef-debug-on-linux)

Comment: @TonyDelroy What about if I want to use #ifdef LOCAL? What do I have to replace that with because #ifdef LOCAL does not also work. Or is it the same thing?

Comment: @AdrianMole I think this is a different topic to that...

Comment: I've never heard of a preprocessor define called `LOCAL` - is that a Windows/VisualC++ or MacOS thing?  If you want to know what preprocessor defines your compiler has by default, check its documentation.  Most compilers have some command line options to get them to output a list of such defines.

Comment: @TonyDelroy I think its a windows thing