# Can `#ifdef` be used inside a macro?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, variadic-macros

I only found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694662/), which isn't quite what I am looking for.

I used to have macros defined inside an `#ifdef` statement:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING(format) printf(format);
#   define PRINTF_IF_DEBUGGING(format, ...) printf(format, __VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING(...)
#   define PRINTF_IF_DEBUGGING(...)
#endif
```

Now, I want to do the inverse, to have the `#ifdef` statements inside the macros. Something like this:

```
#define PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING(format, ...) \
#if defined(DEBUG) print(format); #endif
#define PRINTF_IF_DEBUGGING(format, ...) \
#if defined(DEBUG) printf(format, __VA_ARGS__); #endif
```

However, I am having an issue using `__VA_ARGS__` inside the `#ifdef defined`.

```
error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
 #define PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING(format, ...)
error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
 #define PRINTF_IF_DEBUGGING(format, ...)
warning: __VA_ARGS__ can only appear in the expansion of a C++11 variadic macro
 #if defined(DEBUG) printf(format, __VA_ARGS__); #endif
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The more I look at it the more I wonder _why_ you'd want to abandon something that is readable and works.

Comment: Let's say I was exploring new ways for using Macros. If my intent was possible, I would be able to use `#define DEBUG` to enable the `printf` for a segment of code instead of the entire program code.

Comment: In other words, I would like to the compiler to define the code not when parsing the definition of the macro `PRINTF_IF_DEBUGGING`, but when parsing the use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `#ifdef` *inside* of `#define` , so no, this is not possible.  The first code you showed is the correct solution.

Answer (score 4):

This should really be a comment, but I can't format that in a way that will allow me to say what I want to say, so I'm answering instead.

Anyway, just change this:

```
#if defined(DEBUG) print(format); #endif
```

to this:

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
    print(format);
#endif
```

and so on, and that should fix it.

Comment: Fwiw, I think this _should_ be an answer :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo To quote [Kenneth Wolstenhome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Wolstenholme) RIP, "it is now" :)  Hmmm, I see Wikipedia have fluffed the quote.  Oh well.

Comment: It did not solve the issue. Notice that the issue is on the second macro, the one that can evaluate to `printf(format, __VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: @EduardoReis Your updated code shows that you still try to put multiple preprocessor directives on the same line. That's not what Paul suggested at all.

Comment: Oh right, you have two separate issues.  I missed that, sorry.  I recommend you ask a new question, incorporating the fix described in my answer, so that readers can focus on your problem using `__VA_ARGS__` .  When you do that, please focus on just that issue and show both your macro and how you are invoking it, see [mre].

Comment: PS: I rolled back your edit.  Editing questions that have been answered in a way that renders the answer invalid is a no-no.  And if you take note of and act on what @ted told you, your second problem might go away in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Using `#ifdef` inside of `#define` is not possible. But there are still ways you can detect wether or not a macro has been defined within a macro definition.

##### 1. Solution

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/797rvGvE6)

```cpp
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_IMPL(a, b)
#define CAT_IMPL(a, b) a ## b

#define IS_DEBUG_DEFINED() CHECK((CAT(CHECK_,DEBUG), 0, 1))
#define CHECK_DEBUG ~,~
#define CHECK(tup) CHECK_IMPL tup
#define CHECK_IMPL(a, b, c, ...) c

#define IIF(condition, true_value, false_value) CAT(IIF_,condition)(true_value, false_value)
#define IIF_0(true_value, false_value) false_value
#define IIF_1(true_value, false_value) true_value 

#define PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING(format) IIF(IS_DEBUG_DEFINED(), PRINT_DEBUGGING, PRINT_NOT_DEBUGGING)(format)
// this will be used if DEBUG is defined:
#define PRINT_DEBUGGING(format) debugPrint(format)
// this will be used if DEBUG is NOT defined:
#define PRINT_NOT_DEBUGGING(format) print(format)
```

`PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING(foo)` will expand to:

- if `DEBUG` is defined: `debugPrint(foo)`
- if `DEBUG` is **not** defined: `print(foo)`

Example:

```cpp
PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING("test1");

#define DEBUG
PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING("test2");
#undef DEBUG

PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING("test3");
```

would result in:

```cpp
print("test1");

debugPrint("test2");

print("test3");
```

---

##### 2. How `IS_DEBUG_DEFINED()` works

The fundamental trick behind this is to use [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) - if the macro was defined it will be expanded, otherwise the token will be left unmodified by the preprocessor:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ms1j4ErW1)

```cpp
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_IMPL(a, b)
#define CAT_IMPL(a, b) a ## b

// DEBUG NOT DEFINED:
CAT(CHECK_,DEBUG) // will expand to CHECK_DEBUG

// DEBUG DEFINED:
#define DEBUG 1234
CAT(CHECK_,DEBUG) // will expand to CHECK_1234
```

- The first `CAT` will expand to `CHECK_DEBUG`, because `DEBUG` was not defined.
- The second `CAT` however will expand to `CHECK_1234`, because `DEBUG` was defined and expanded to `1234` before the concatenation with `CHECK_`.

---

By defining a macro named `CHECK_DEBUG` we can change the result if the macro was not defined, e.g.:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hhPEz953G)

```cpp
#define TEST CAT(CHECK_,DEBUG), 0, 1
#define CHECK_DEBUG ~,~
```

- If `DEBUG` is not defined the result will be `~, ~, 0, 1` (**4** comma-separated tokens)
- If `DEBUG` is defined the result will be `CHECK_, 0, 1` (**3** comma-separated tokens)

Notice how we got 4 tokens in the first case, but only 3 tokens in the second.

Now all we need to do is take the 3rd token from that sequence (which will be `0` if `DEBUG` is not defined and `1` otherwise), for example with a simple macro that always returns the 3rd argument:

```cpp
#define CHECK(a, b, c, ...) c
```

---

Putting it all together, this is what a full `IS_DEBUG_DEFINED()` could look like:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bYj18s6Mn)

```cpp
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_IMPL(a, b)
#define CAT_IMPL(a, b) a ## b

#define IS_DEBUG_DEFINED() CHECK((CAT(CHECK_,DEBUG), 0, 1))
#define CHECK_DEBUG ~,~
#define CHECK(tup) CHECK_IMPL tup
#define CHECK_IMPL(a, b, c, ...) c
```

`IS_DEBUG_DEFINED()` will expand to `0` if `DEBUG` is not defined, and `1` if it is, e.g.:

```cpp
IS_DEBUG_DEFINED() // -> 0

#define DEBUG
IS_DEBUG_DEFINED() // -> 1
#undef DEBUG

IS_DEBUG_DEFINED() // -> 0
```

---

With `IS_DEBUG_DEFINED()` you can then use a standard preprocessor [`IIF`](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms#pattern-matching) to change the behaviour of your macro depending on wether `DEBUG` is defined or not.

Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/79K7q71W1)

```cpp
#define IIF(condition, true_value, false_value) CAT(IIF_,condition)(true_value, false_value)
#define IIF_0(true_value, false_value) false_value
#define IIF_1(true_value, false_value) true_value 

#define PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING(format) IIF(IS_DEBUG_DEFINED(), PRINT_DEBUGGING, PRINT_NOT_DEBUGGING)(format)
// this will be used if DEBUG is defined:
#define PRINT_DEBUGGING(format) debugPrint(format)
// this will be used if DEBUG is NOT defined:
#define PRINT_NOT_DEBUGGING(format) print(format)


PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING("test"); // -> print("test");

#define DEBUG
PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING("test"); // -> debugPrint("test");
#undef DEBUG

PRINT_IF_DEBUGGING("test"); // -> print("test");
```

---

##### 3. Caveats

One small caveat with this is that if `DEBUG` is defined it must expand to a valid preprocessing token (so it **must** only contain letters, digits and underscores) - otherwise the concatenation will result in an error.

So this would **not** work:

```
#define DEBUG ()
#define DEBUG +
```