# How to make DEBUG macros portable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, portability

I know the words "portable" and "macro" don't often go together, but my code is generally riddled with `#ifdef _DEBUG` tags (I use VS2012) that confirm desired outcomes. I want to make my code portable to Unix systems.

My understanding, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290509/debug-vs-ndebug), is that Visual Studio uses `_DEBUG` and the C-standard uses `NDEBUG`, but that their functions are different (`_DEBUG` flags debug mode, `NDEBUG` flags assertions).

If I want my code to be as portable as possible, should I use `#ifndef NDEBUG` if I only ever want those lines of code to run when asserts are active? What are the consequences of this within Visual Studio? It seems to work but I want to make sure there's nothing I'm missing; ie. why would microsoft use `_DEBUG` when there's a perfectly good C-standard alternative? Historic reasons?

Comment: "as portable as possible" - does that mean across all architectures (16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit), all operating systems, all processor, all endian-ness???  I would restate what level of portability you are looking for.  I also would not recommend using Microsoft as the basis for doing anything "portable" (their header files are filled with "WIntel" implementations).

Comment: @franji1 I don't think endianness and architecture is relevant in this instance. As I am asking about macros I would consider the solution to be portable if it works on any standard c++ compiler under windows and linux. Let's assume the rest of my code is completely portable. Everywhere.

Comment: Just making sure you looked at the primary portation issues.  MSVS based projects are typically NOT very portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the real reason for MS not using the NDEBUG macro, and defining the _DEBUG instead. My my guess is that it is related to the definition of `_ASSERT` instead of `assert`.

The problem with `assert()` is that the C standard defines requires it to print a line to the console and `abort` the program. But Windows programs don't usually have a console, so MS thought that it would be nice to pop up a window instead. But that `assert()` pops up a window would not be standard compliant, so the developed a similar but different macro:`_ASSERT`, and a different macro to control its behavior: `_DEBUG`.

A similar mess exists with the `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE` macros, but that's another story...

Note that in the default configuration of a Visual C++ project, in debug mode `_DEBUG` is defined, but `NDEBUG` is not. While in release mode `_DEBUG` is not defined, but `NDEBUG` is. So for your own code, you can use any one of them. But naturally, if you want to be portable you should use `NDEBUG`, as the `_DEBUG` name is reserved to the compiler implementation.

Comment: Note: MS does use NDEBUG for asserts (as expected). But they also have other macros that are specifically theirs (just like any other compiler).

Answer (score 3):

That ship sailed a long time ago, MSVC complied because resistance was *futile*.  This works as you'd expect:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#pragma message("Release build selected")
#endif
```

That macro doesn't completely fall from the sky, like [some do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  Project + Properties, C/C++, Preprocessor, Preprocessor definitions setting.  It works not because the compiler joined the Borg, the IDE did.  Or to be a bit more specific, the project template did.  A very good excuse :)

So no, making macros portable is completely not a problem.  It only takes getting your makefile correct.

Answer (score 1):

Albeit a bit contrived, you can do this to make it somewhat portable-er

```
#if defined(__unix__) && defined(NDEBUG)
#define _DEBUG
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only thing (by standard), `NDEBUG` should affect is `assert` macro. Therefore, if one wants to add their debugging facilities, he adds his own macro definitions like `_DEBUG` (which do not affect or depend on `NDEBUG`).

To make your debugging code portable, you're likely better off defining your own macro for the same purpose.

Then as an option, you could turn it on and off, say, depending on `NDEBUG` presence.

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing in C that prevents you from using `NDEBUG` to conditionally compile your own code.

Comment: Well, yes, you sure can. It's just that your code will depend one something which is supposed to turn off and on assert macro. Which may not be a bad thing of course.